# Why namespace is passed to spl_autoload_register and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, closures, autoload

I'm currently doing this but it doesn't look right to me:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name){
    $class_name = str_replace('MyNameSpace\\', '', $class_name . '.php');

    require $class_name;
});
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace is passed because it has to be.  How else would the autoloader function know the difference between `Foo\Bar` and `Baz\Bar`? :-)

Your method looks okay if you're absolutely sure that you won't ever need to load classes with the same names as those found in `MyNameSpace`.  The canonical method to autoloading classes involves using the parts of the namespace as file system structure, so that, for example, `foo\bar\Baz` can be found at path `foo/bar/Baz.php`.